# UI router resolve do not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Right now i am trying to make an Angular JS install application, to install a CMS. So i am trying to block access to a state (ui router), i am doing it with a resolve function. But the problem is, that i make a get request to an API, which returns true or false, and the resolve function do not wait for the get request to complete, so it just loads the state.

Here is my code:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    $http.get('/api/v1/getSetupStatus').success(function(res) {
      $rootScope.setupdb = res.db_setup;
      $rootScope.setupuser = res.user_setup;
    });
  });
}]);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

  $stateProvider.state('db-install', {
      url: "/install/db",
      templateUrl: 'admin/js/partials/db-install.html',
      controller: 'DBController',
      resolve: {
        data: function($q, $state, $timeout, $rootScope) {
          var setupStatus = $rootScope.setupdb;
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $timeout(function() {
            if (setupStatus === true) {
              $state.go('setup-done');
              deferred.reject();
            } else {
              deferred.resolve();
            }
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .state('user-registration', {
      url: "/install/user-registration",
      templateUrl: "admin/js/partials/user-registration.html",
      controller: "RegisterController"
    })
    .state('setup-done', {
      url: "/install/setup-done",
      templateUrl: "admin/js/partials/setup-done.html"
    })
    .state('404', {
      url: "/404",
      templateUrl: "admin/js/partials/404.html"
    });
}]);
```

**Here you can see a timeline for the loading of the page:**
[image: The timeline]

**Here you can see what the API returns:** 
[image: What the API returns]

Answer (score 0):

Your `db-install` resolver function needs to **chain** from the `$http.get` for install status.

```
$stateProvider.state('db-install', {
    url: "/install/db",
    templateUrl: 'admin/js/partials/db-install.html',
    controller: 'DBController',
    resolve: {
        data: function($state, $http) {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/getSetupStatus'
                       ).then (function(result) {
                           var setupdb = result.data.db_setup;
                           var user_setup = result.data.user_setup;
                           //return for chaining
                           return setupdb;
                       }).then (function (setupStatus) {
                           //use chained value
                           if (setupStatus === true {
                               //chain with $state.go promise
                               return $state.go('setup-done');
                           } else {
                               //resolve promise chain
                               return 'setup-not-done';
                           };
                       })
        }    
    }
})
```

By **returning** and **chaining** from the status `$http.get`, the resolver function waits before executing (or not executing) the `$state.go`.

For more information on **chaining promises**, see the [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

Answer (score -1):

The call to `getSetupStatus` gets executed in the `$stateChangeStart` so `resolve` is not aware that it has to wait. You can put the `$http` call inside of the resolve function, like this:

```
function($q, $state, $timeout) {
return $http.get('/api/v1/getSetupStatus')
  .then(function(res) {
      if(res.db_setup) {
         $state.go('setup-done');
      }
      else {
         return true;
      }
  });
}
```

By making the `resolve` parameter return a callback the state will load after the [promise is resolved](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider).

Comment: If i have the $http request inside the resolve, then why have a rootscope?

Comment: Probably shouldn't answer questions at 3 in the morning again. That code should have been commented out, in any case the resolve would work.